# Eloquent's sum() Results to Zero after skip()

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have ran into a problem with regards to standalone Eloquent. I have a query like this:

```
$data = TestModel::where('total', '>', 0 )->take(10)->skip(0)->get();
```

When I do a:

```
$val = $data->sum('total');
```

It would return the sum of total properly without any issues. But once a I make the skip() function to be like: `->skip(10)` or any number greater than zero, it will return the `$data->sum()` with 0 value.

The SQL for the query are as follows:

skip = 0

```
select * from `test` where `total` > ? order by `date` desc
```

skip > 0 (Includes take of 10)

```
select * from `test` where `total` > ? order by `date` desc limit 10 offset 1
```

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL queries you pasted are not the queries that are run when you call **sum()**. When this method is called Eloquent does not fetch the results and calculate sum of **total** column on the result collection - instead it modifies the query that you've built and calls the following SQL queries:

```
select SUM(total) from `test` where `total` > ? order by `date` desc
select SUM(total) from `test` where `total` > ? order by `date` desc limit 10 offset 1
```

Those queries result in a single row response. Therefore, when you apply **skip()** method on your query, you skip this first, single row and as a result you get **0** as the result.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to apply the skip() and take() for the sum() method?

Comment: I assume you want to count the sum for only some rows? You'll need to filter them using WHERE conditions, e.g. fetch the list of IDs using skip/take and then do the sum() using whereIn('id', $list_of_ids)

Comment: Yes. Only some rows. But I want to limit the result to say 10 items only with 10 row offset. This is for paginated sum total

Comment: As I said, you can't do it with a single query - you need 2 queries (you can do it with Eloquent) or a query with subselect, but here you'd need to use raw SQL, something similar to SELECT SUM(total) FROM test WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM total LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1) -